# Using std::vector as vertex/element lists with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw a bunch quads.

Right now I have a problem; drawing works fine and is fast but I'm using std::vector as containers for my quads and they're really, really slow. Coming from XNA I figured I should create something like the spriteBatch so that I can just call DrawQuad() to add the given quad to a list and then finally call End() to draw every quad.

My current code generally prints something like this to the console:

```
DrawQuad(): 77
End(): 0
```

Over and over again.

Main.cpp (sf::Clock is the clock class in [SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/))

```
sf::Clock time;
for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        renderer.DrawQuad("A", Vector2<GLfloat>(-1.0f + x * 0.02f, -1.0f + y * 0.02f));
std::cout << "DrawQuad(): " << time.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() << std::endl;
```

Renderer.cpp:

```
void TextRenderer::DrawQuad(string text, Vector2<GLfloat> position)
{
    //TOP LEFT
    vertexBufferVector.push_back(position.X);
    vertexBufferVector.push_back(position.Y);

    //TOP RIGHT
    vertexBufferVector.push_back(position.X + 0.02f);
    vertexBufferVector.push_back(position.Y);

    //BOTTOM RIGHT
    vertexBufferVector.push_back(position.X + 0.02f);
    vertexBufferVector.push_back(position.Y + 0.02f);

    //BOTTOM LEFT
    vertexBufferVector.push_back(position.X);
    vertexBufferVector.push_back(position.Y + 0.02f);

    int elementCount = elementBufferVector.size() / 6; 

    elementBufferVector.push_back(elementCount * 4);
    elementBufferVector.push_back(elementCount * 4 + 1);
    elementBufferVector.push_back(elementCount * 4 + 2);

    elementBufferVector.push_back(elementCount * 4 + 2);
    elementBufferVector.push_back(elementCount * 4 + 3);
    elementBufferVector.push_back(elementCount * 4);
}

void TextRenderer::End()
{
    sf::Clock time;

    GLfloat* vertexArray = &vertexBufferVector[0];
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexBufferVector.size(), vertexArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    GLint* elementArray = &elementBufferVector[0];
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLint) * elementBufferVector.size(), elementArray, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, elementBufferVector.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    vertexBufferVector.clear();
    elementBufferVector.clear();

    std::cout << "End(): " << time.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds() << std::endl;
}
```

How do people who know what they're doing solve this? 10000 quads really shouldn't be an issue.

After writing all this I also increased the looping from (100, 100) to (1000, 100) and now the drawing takes 4-5 ms, is that considered good? I'm thinking no...

Comment: 4ms is approximately 250 fps, is that too slow?

Comment: I should comment on the "A" argument given to DrawQuad: at first I wanted to make something which can draw text but I started off with this so it's just there.

Roger: I don't know... That's why I asked. But the 800ms it takes to call DrawQuad that many times is too much

Comment: 4-5 ms for 100k quads is okay considering you are recreating the vertex arrays for every frame. OpenGL should have a way to create a static vertex buffer that works much faster as long as you do not change its contents.

Comment: That makes sense Riv. I don't see a way of doing this with a static buffer so I'll just have to be satisfied with what I have

Comment: Your DrawQuads calls aren't quite as slow as that on my machine (using g++-4.7.2 with default optimisations they take 5-11ms) but removing the unused string halves that and then going to -O3 brings it down to less than about 1ms.  I'd definitely check what timing you get without the string because at the moment you're creating and destroying one on every loop iteration which is relatively costly.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Mike, I set my optimization settings to /O2 to maximize speed and I removed the string (didn't think about that). I'm down to lower and acceptable numbers like you. It takes 3 ms to call DrawQuad() and end() takes about 4 when I loop through it 100000 times. I suppose that's good enough.

Comment: *"but I'm using `std::vector` as containers for my quads and they're really, really slow"* - No, they aren't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is dead I'll just answer my question and maybe it'll help someone.

Instead of using vectors I resorted to using arrays with a set size. This brought the total rendering time for 100000 quads (with textures as well) down to an average of ~3.260ms.

My .h looks like this now:

```
const int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1000;
const int MAX_VERTEX_BUFFER_SIZE = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE * 16;
const int MAX_ELEMENT_BUFFER_SIZE = MAX_BUFFER_SIZE * 6;

...

GLint vertexBufferArrayInserts;
GLfloat vertexBufferArray[MAX_VERTEX_BUFFER_SIZE];
GLint elementBufferArray[MAX_ELEMENT_BUFFER_SIZE];
```

And the relevant parts of the .cpp file:

```
void TextRenderer::DrawQuad(Vector2<GLfloat> position)
{
    if(vertexBufferArrayInserts == MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)
        End();

    //TOP LEFT
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16] = position.X;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 1] = position.Y;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 2] = 0.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 3] = 0.0f;

    //TOP RIGHT
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 4] = position.X + 16.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 5] = position.Y;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 6] = 24.0f / 512.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 7] = 0.0f;

    //BOTTOM RIGHT
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 8] = position.X + 16.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 9] = position.Y + 16.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 10] = 24.0f / 512.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 11] = 32.0f / 512.0f;

    //BOTTOM LEFT
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 12] = position.X;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 13] = position.Y + 16.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 14] = 0.0f;
    vertexBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16 + 15] = 32.0f / 512.0f;


    //ELEMENT BUFFER
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 1] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 1;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 2] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 2;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 3] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 2;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 4] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4 + 3;
    elementBufferArray[vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6 + 5] = vertexBufferArrayInserts * 4;

    vertexBufferArrayInserts++;
}

void TextRenderer::End()
{
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * vertexBufferArrayInserts * 16, vertexBufferArray);

    glBufferSubData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(GLint) *  vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6, elementBufferArray);

    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, vertexBufferArrayInserts * 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

    vertexBufferArrayInserts = 0;
}
```

And this is how I timed it:

```
sf::Clock timer;
renderer.Begin(projMatrix);

for (int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
    for(int x = 0; x < 1000; x++)
        renderer.DrawQuad(Vector2<GLfloat>(16.0f * x, 16.0f * y));

renderer.End();

avgDrawTime += timer.getElapsedTime().asMicroseconds();
drawCalls++;

if(drawCalls % 100 == 0)
    std::cout << avgDrawTime / drawCalls << std::endl;
```